# How to refresh DataGridView cells style

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have this simple piece of code on a windows form containing said DataGridView (dgvStatsTable) :

```
    public void LoadStatsTable(DataTable statsTable)
    {
        dgvStatsTable.DataSource = statsTable;

        var smallFont = new Font(dgvStatsTable.Font.FontFamily, dgvStatsTable.Font.Size * 0.67f);
        dgvStatsTable.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.Font = smallFont;
        dgvStatsTable.InvalidateCell(0, 0);

        //dgvStatsTable.Invalidate();
        dgvStatsTable.Refresh();
    }
```

Once that function has been called, my DataGridView contains the correct data to see.
However, that style change that I wanted is not showing (first cell in top-right corner has to have smaller text).

Why?

Is it because the table is set to a DataSource rather than building rows and columns?

Thanks!

Comment: did you check your header row's top-right corner i think row[0] is the header row... and cell [0] is top-left...

Comment: thanks, I tried also Rows[1].Cells[1] but all cells still have the same font size

Comment: hmm, I'm looking into it, in the mean time you can take a look at this, if you haven't already, it might help. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0.aspx

Comment: also, here is the documentation on the font property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.font(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: hey thanks! I checked your article and did as they suggested in the section : Setting Styles Dynamically. I implemented the logic in DataGridView.CellFormatting and now it works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Solution to the problem was to write a handler for the DataGridView.CellFormatting Event

found in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0.aspx) in the Setting Styles Dynamically section.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very nice answer from MSDN network, it appears that in order to have greater control you will need to override some functions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fb61s43(VS.80).aspx